# Add .js extension on TypeScript build

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, module, tsconfig

If I import a file `import * as test from './dir/file'`, the .js extension is missing in the build

I want the output file like this `import * as test from './dir/file.js'`

The problem is: YES I can add the .js manually BUT many libraries doesn't have the .js extension manually added, and I don't want to go through all files of a library and add the extension manually.

And I know there are some regex replacer out there which add the .js extension. But is this the only way?? Is there no way to tell TypeScript to add the .js (maybe via tsconfig.json)???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending .js extension on relative import statements during Typescript compilation (ES6 modules)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619058/appending-js-extension-on-relative-import-statements-during-typescript-compilat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a github issue opened about this, check it out [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577) for workarounds, as I don't think it is possible with current ts compiler.

Comment: Another potential workaround: https://github.com/olalonde/tsc-module-loader